# Update с разными условиями

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle

Как можно составить update, чтобы в столбец  REZOBR_INT2 заполнялись данными с разными условиями. Получается последнее условие у меня срабатывает и затирает два первых.

```
update t_table t 
set REZOBR_INT2 = '1.Дана Консультация'
where ((type_id = 3) 
and EXISTS (select * from t_block_outboundmess w where date_redirect is null)
and conect_id in (1,7)
and present_id in (1)
and EXISTS (select * from t_block_ger p where regname <> username))
and EXISTS (select * from t_block_ger p where date_end is not null);
--commit;
update t_table t 
set REZOBR_INT2 = '2.Рассмотрено обращение'
where ((present_id = 2)
and EXISTS (select * from t_block_outboundmess w where date_response is not null)
and (letter_num is null)
and EXISTS (select * from t_block_ger p where date_end is not null));
--commit;
update t_table t 
set REZOBR_INT2 = '3.Заявление удовлетворено'
where ((type_id = 2)
and (satisf='ДА')
and EXISTS (select * from t_block_ger p where date_end is not null));
--commit;
```

Comment: `and REZOBR_INT2 not in('1.Дана Консультация', '2.Рассмотрено обращение')` ?

Comment: Можно поподробнее

Comment: Добавьте это условие в последний запрос (и аналогичное, но с одним значением - во второй). Оно не позволит обновить запись, обновлённую в предыдущих запросах.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если формально, то

```
update t_table t 
set REZOBR_INT2 = CASE WHEN     ((type_id = 3) 
                            and EXISTS (select * from t_block_outboundmess w where date_redirect is null)
                            and conect_id in (1,7)
                            and present_id in (1)
                            and EXISTS (select * from t_block_ger p where regname <> username))
                            and EXISTS (select * from t_block_ger p where date_end is not null)
                       THEN '1.Дана Консультация'
                       WHEN     ((present_id = 2)
                            and EXISTS (select * from t_block_outboundmess w where date_response is not null)
                            and (letter_num is null)
                            and EXISTS (select * from t_block_ger p where date_end is not null))
                       THEN '2.Рассмотрено обращение'
                       WHEN     ((type_id = 2)
                            and (satisf='ДА')
                            and EXISTS (select * from t_block_ger p where date_end is not null))
                       THEN '3.Заявление удовлетворено'
                       ELSE REZOBR_INT2
                   END;
```

Comment: а `case` если наткнётся на выполняемое условие остальные не проверяет?

Comment: @4per Именно так. [CASE Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/expressions004.htm#SQLRF20037) *In a searched CASE expression, Oracle searches from left to right until it finds an occurrence of condition that is true, and then returns return_expr.*

Comment: В конце выборки поставил      ELSE 'Не известно'  END;

Comment: Нашел у себя ошибку, не выполняется это условие

and EXISTS (select * from t_block_ger p where regname <> username))

Т.е. столбец regname у меня с таблицы t_block_ger, а столбец username с таблицы t_table
Как можно поправить?

Comment: @dmr *В конце выборки поставил `ELSE 'Не известно' END`* Боюсь, что напрасно... ведь запрос обновляет ВСЕ записи таблицы - в т.ч. и те, которые ранее получили какое-то значение... хотя фиг знает, надо оно тебе или нет. *Как можно поправить?* Если в запросе используется более одной таблицы, возьмите за правило КАЖДОМУ полю во всём тексте запроса указывать, из какой таблицы оно берётся. Т.е. для данного фрагмента это будет `and EXISTS (select * from t_block_ger p where p.regname <> t.username))`. И не используйте один и тот же алиас в двух местах (тут много алиасов `p` - сделайте `p1`,`p2`, ..).

Comment: Да вроде алиас p у меня только у таблицы t_block_ger.
Похоже  алиасs в таких выражениях не показывает ожидаемый результат
and EXISTS (select * from t_block_ger p where regname <> t.username))

Comment: *вроде алиас p у меня только у таблицы t_block_ger.* Угу... только тех таблиц 4 копии - вот у каждой копии должен быть свой, уникальный, алиас. Даже если у них нет общей области видимости - всё спокойнее... *алиасs в таких выражениях не показывает ожидаемый результат* Не бывает. Если указана таблица, поле берётся именно из неё, без вариантов. Если с данном месте эта таблица невидима - будет ошибка unknown token или типа того.

Comment: Да вы правы, нужно указывать алиасы. В данной строчке решил так   and EXISTS (select * from t_block_ger p where regname <> username and p.ger_id = t.id ))